# Ayuda con impresora Zebra IMZ320 BlueTooh. imprimir Texto

Tags: android-studio

Amigos soy medio nuevo en programación android studio, tengo una impresora termica Zebra IMZ320, leo en algunos lugares que descargue el sdk. pero no entiendo ni nada, hay una apk de prueba de ellos llamada Zebra utilites, que hace lo que quiero pero no dan el fuente, estoy super perdido, ya una vez programe para otra impresora china pero esa si traía un programa ejemplo y solo fue cuestión de integrar eso a mi app. pero con esta impresora no entiendo nada. Ayuda por favor

Comment: Hola que tal una pregunta ya pudiste resolver lo de la impresora lo que pasa es que tengo el mismo proyecto y no se nada y es el mismo modelo de la impresora

Comment: hola hermano nada, ese proyecto de la zebra lo dejamos y usamos una impresora china menos complicada, no he terminado con lo de la zebra